# How to repeat a javascript function with a clock

Tags: javascript, date, time, repeat

I am just starting to learn javascirpt and I'm trying to make my own clock widget.  It seems when I use the "ourDate.toLocalString()"  it only displays the time as it was when the function was called.  So I figured I would have to repeat the function continuously for each second in order for it to continuously keep the current time.  But the problem I have is when I start the script, it repeats the function only one time.  What am I doing wrong?  Below is the code:

```
function updateclock(){
ourDate = new Date();
document.write(ourDate.toLocaleString());
}

function startclock() {
updateclock();
setInterval("updateclock()", 1000); 
}
```

Comment: This should work. However: don't use strings as the first argument to `setInterval` and the family, use function value itself: `setInterval(updateClock, 1000)`. Oh, and don't use `document.write` - use `console.log` if you're debugging, or `document.createElement` (or jQuery) for real work.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is `document.write`. If you call that after the document has loaded, **it will overwrite the whole document**, including your `startclock` function, that cannot be called anymore.

Update the content of an HTML element instead:

```
<div id="clock"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateclock(){
    ourDate = new Date();
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = ourDate.toLocaleString();
}

function startclock() {
    updateclock();
    setInterval(updateclock, 1000); 
}
startclock();
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ys87F/

Also: do not pass a string to `setInterval` (or `setTimeout`), pass the function name instead.

Comment: Awesome bfavaretto!  that was it.  Thank you so much.  And thank you for the advise too.  Even though I don't fully understand it all, I'm going to study this coding to see how it all works.  Now, on to styling it with css to make it like I want it.

Comment: @TonyWilkerson Concerning the `setInterval` advice, [this is why](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!).

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this instead:

```
setInterval(updateclock, 1000);
```

Comment: same stuff but without `eval`